# Drupal Views referencing content node

Tags: drupal, view, entityreference

How can I get a Views block to query information from the page it's assigned to and filter it's output?

Please see graphic below to see what I'm trying to accomplish. (Open in new tab to enlarge)

[views relationship http://reubenlara.com/blog/views-relationship.jpg](http://reubenlara.com/blog/views-relationship.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar use case here and it solved it.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12388/making-a-view-with-a-node-reference-argument

R